# Converting HashMap to Sorted ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap

I have a `HashMap<String, Integer>` containing words along with their frequencies. I need to now convert this `HashMap` into an `ArrayList` of just the words, discarding of the frequencies, but i also want the `ArrayList` to be *sorted in descending order* of words by frequency.

Does anyone know an efficient way to do this?

Comment: this is a pretty standard request, you should easily be able to find stuff in the internet. Did you try something yet?

Comment: for example, you could create a class `Word` that holds the `String` and the frequency and implements the `Comparable` interface comparing `Word` objects by their frequency. Then populate an `ArrayList<Word>` from the `HashMap` and then call `Collections.sort(yourArrayList)`

Comment: I recently had the exact some assignment to do. I don't know if it's the best solution, but instead of a `Map<String, Integer>` I've used an `ArrayList<MyClass>`, where `MyClass` contains the `String word` and `int/double frequency`. You can then use the `Collections.sort(yourList, new Comparator<MyClass>(){ @Override public int compare(MyClass mc1, MyClass mc2){ ... } });` to sort it

Comment: I have an idea but id like the most efficient way of doing it, which i don't think is what i have in mind. Perhaps converting the `HashMap` into a `TreeMap`, sorting it using a `comparator` then iterating over the elements and loading into an `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`HashMap` has a convenient method called [`entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29), which lets you access a collection of key-value pairs. You can use it to construct a `List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>`.

Now you have something you can sort. Use a sort method with a custom comparator, which orders entries with higher frequencies toward the beginning of the list.

With a sorted list in hand, all you need to do is walk it, and harvest the words which are now in the proper order.

```
List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> entries = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>(
    freqMap.entrySet()
);
Collections.sort(
    entries
,   new Comparator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>() {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<String,Integer> a, Map.Entry<String,Integer> b) {
            return Integer.compare(b.getValue(), a.getValue());
        }
    }
);
for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> e : entries) {
    // This loop prints entries. You can use the same loop
    // to get the keys from entries, and add it to your target list.
    System.out.println(e.getKey()+":"+e.getValue());
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/KeA9RO)

Answer (score 8):

When using **Java 8** you can make use of the [Stream API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) like follows:

```
final Map<String, Integer> wordStats = new HashMap<>();
// some dummy data:
wordStats.put("twice", 2);
wordStats.put("thrice", 3);
wordStats.put("once", 1);

final List<String> sortedStats = wordStats.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue, Comparator.reverseOrder()))
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    // or to specify the list implementation:
    //.collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);

// Output
sortedStats.forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Output:**

```
thrice
twice
once
```

Comment: Great answer, +1-- Any significance behind using `final`?

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you can also do this shorter variation of what has been answered

*Ascending order*

```
ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> sorted = newArrayList<>(frequencies.entrySet());
sorted.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue));
```

*Descending order*

```
ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> sorted = new ArrayList<>(frequencies.entrySet());
sorted.sort(Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Put your map in a sortedmap defining your own comparator.
- Convert the keySet of the sorted map to a list.